# Local webserver iOS connection error

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, webserver, http

I'm running a local webserver on my Windows 7 computer that is connected with my router through WiFi. All Firewall and Antivirus features are disabled on that computer. When I try to access my webserver using another Windows computer, there is no problem, it shows the webpage as it should. But when i'm trying to access the same webserver using my iPhone 6, it keeps loading and doesn't show anything. The page is plane html, so ít shouldn't have any problems loading scripts.

The funny thing is, when I disable my WiFi and connect the computer running the webserver through an internet cable, it works on Windows computers as on my iPhone.

Using this information I can conclude that it has nothing to do with my iPhone. But what can be the problem on my Windows computer running the webserver?

Comment: Obviously, you didn't tell us which path the iPhone connection will try to take to connect to your server. One possible cause of the problem you observe is certainly that your WiFi is set up to isolate clients from each other.

Comment: I'm talking about a very small, private home network with a maximum of 10 devices. I'm using the default Cisco modem/router from my ISP.

Router: 192.168.1.1 --- 
Win7 PC (with webserver): LAN: 192.168.1.13 | WIFI: 192.168.1.16 --- 
Other Windows PC: WIFI: 192.168.1.14 --- 
iPhone 6: 192.168.1.12 --- 

All connections will just go to the router and from there to the webserver's ip.

I know that my WiFi doesn't isolate clients because the other Windows PC CAN connect when both server and client are on WiFi.

Comment: Which URLs do you use to try to access the Win PC with the web server on which device? -- Does your plain HTML maybe refer to any include files for CSS or HTML artefacts?